# Clipping in game's sound

Tags: gameaudio, clipping

I learned that in computer there is a limit of amplitude that you can store of a sample. (0 dB) If you boost the sound past that point then clipping occurs.

In my game I have 1 BGM (no clipping, average loudness -0.3dB) and 1 SFX (no clipping, average loudness -0.3dB) now why when I play these two file at the same time, it sounds like clipping occurs? It's like two waveform adds up each other and resulting in over 0 dB. But this is a playback, not storing in a limited space so clipping should not happen at all?

Another question, is it impossible to create a clipping-free game? Because unlike conventional music which you carefully mix things to a perfect shape, in a game you never know that your player will or won't do something outrageous and make a really loud sound like gather 100 enemies and destroy them at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will clip. The waves are **summed** together, so at the points where both waves are in phase, the system is adding the signals together and it goes over the maximum. Try putting the two sounds on two tracks in your DAW and playing them - it will also clip. Exactly the same thing happens in your game.

I find it simplifies the concept to think in normalised values. The baseline is 0, fully below the baseline is -1, fully above is 1. Anything above 1 clips. Summing 2 sounds which are within -0.5 and 0.5 will not clip because they can never go over 1, summing two sounds which are over that will clip the system.

And yes, it is possible to create a clip free game. Careful setting of levels and use of dynamics processing (limiting, compressing) is the answer. Generally though, you need to leave more headroom.

Answer (score 0):

Lower both sounds - there's not much reason why they need to be just below clipping.

Another way is using a limiter.